# Is it possible to add a text and unicode characters to a cosmos gui?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, operating-system, cosmos

I was wondering if it would be possible to add text to a GUI in cosmos in another way then drawing it out line by line.

Maybe this could be achieved if only a small portion of the screen is GUI and the other part is still console allowing for text in a console if that is possible.

Comment: Always nice to ask the same question on multiple places: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1248679/Is-it-possible-to-add-a-text-and-unicode-character
If you spent **ages** doing research on that and you haven't found anything in their documentation it's probably not possible.

Comment: Thank You for your Insight. It's probably true since I only come to forums as a last resort as I know peoples time is valuable and I usually research quite thoroughly.